# How can I constrain XML content to other content in the XML (as a reference)?

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I want to validate [XML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236945/188148) if and only if there is a bijection from `id=*` in `method/key` and `{*}` substrings in `method/call`.

1. Valid because every `{*}` corresponds with exactly on `id=*`
   and vice-versa.

   ```
   <format>
     <call>
       /tags/{1}/top-askers/{2}
     </call>
     <key id="1">
       <name>tag</name>
       <discussion>a tag for the site</discussion>
     </key>
     <key id="2">
       <name>period</name>
     </key>
   </format>
   ```
2. Invalid because there is an `id=*` that has no corresponding `{*}`.

   ```
   <format>
     <call>
       /tags/{1}
     </call>
     <key id="1">
       <name>tag</name>
       <discussion>a tag for the site</discussion>
     </key>
     <key id="2">
       <name>period</name>
     </key>
   </format>
   ```
3. Invalid because there is an `{*}` that has no corresponding `id=*`.

   ```
   <format>
     <call>
       /tags/{1}/top-askers/{2}
     </call>
     <key id="1">
       <name>tag</name>
       <discussion>a tag for the site</discussion>
     </key>
   </format>
   ```
4. Ideally, I would also like this to be possible as well, meaning that the contents of `{*}` could be any of `[^}{]`.

   ```
   <format>
     <call>
       /tags/{tag}/top-askers/{2}
     </call>
     <key id="tag">
       <name>tag</name>
       <discussion>a tag for the site</discussion>
     </key>
     <key id="2">
       <name>period</name>
     </key>
   </format>
   ```

I've looked at the w3schools reference for XML schema, but it doesn't seem to list any such capabilities.  It's certainly not a complete reference of the spec, though.  Is this possible within XML schema?

### Update

@JirkaŠ has provided the following expression which solves (2) (and (4)) but not (3):

```
for $key in /format/key
  return matches($key/../call,
                 concat("\{", $key/@id, "\}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, in XSD 1.0 this is not possible. Of course there some basic constraints (xs:unique, xs:key). These are defined using a XPath expression but this expression is only subset of the whole XPath language (see chapter 9.2.5 in http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_02.htm). 
The most restricting in this case is the fact that function calls are not allowed and you probably need some string manipulation function, because "call" element content is a string.

If you can use XSD 1.1 there are some other capabilities how to express more complicated restrictions, especcialy I have "xs:assert" on my mind. I think xpath function might be called in XSD 1.1.

Comment: This is totally possible using the `for` expression in XPath 2.0; do you want to take a stab at it while I'm at work? It looks like a fun problem to solve (if you roll that way). If not, I can try to take a stab during lunch (if nothing more pressing pops up at work…).

Comment: Where is your xpath expression located? In XSD? Could you provide it with corresponding xsd definition?

Comment: Probably something like `for $key in /format/key return matches($key/../call, concat("\{", $key/@id, "\}")) ` could work?

Comment: That at least gets half of the story—I'll update my original post here shortly.

Comment: Hm, 3 is a real challenge (at least for me). I tried something like `for $call in /format/call, $id in tokenize(normalize-space($call), '\{|\}')[position() mod 2 = 0] return $call/../key/@id = $id` for this. But it is not bulletproof solution because I'm not expert at regex (it would fail e.g. if there was `}` without corresponding `{`). But it could be some inspiration for you.